# orderBy: sort by a user selected predicate and predefined secondary

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting

I am trying to sort a table of results first by a user selected predicate, and then by a predefined secondary.

For example, my ng-repeat is set up like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="line in model.resultList | orderBy:['-predicate', 'secondary_value'] | limitTo:model.pageSize:model.beginFrom">
```

...where predicate is defined in the controller's scope as `$scope.predicate`, and there is logic which changes this name based on user choices.

I can sort without issue just using the predicate on its own (e.g. `orderBy:predicate:reverse`)

Am I approaching this the wrong way? Are $scope values allowed to be used in an orderBy array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove quotes. The values in brackets without quotes should be variables defined in `$scope`

```
orderBy: [predicate, 'secondary_value']
```

Mind that `[-predicate]` is not a valid expression. In case predicate value should be dynamic (taken from `$scope`) it is the value of variable `$scope.predicate` that should contain value with hyphen at the beginning for reverse order, ex.: `$scope.predicate = '-name';`

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Grety/u24gvn1y/3/)

Comment: Ahh, excellent. Thank you very much. It was in fact the '-' that was causing me issues. Thanks again.